# Consumer - Producer problem with named pipes in C

Tags: c, unix, pipe, ipc, producer-consumer

I have challenge to implement two task using named pipes in C:

- Multiple producer - single consumer
- Single producer - multiple consumer

I already did single producer - single consumer problem but I'm not sure how can I start solving above tasks, can you advice me in that by recomanding suitable approach and methods?

Here is my single producer - single consument code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

const int dataAmountToProduce = 10;
int value = 0;
int const buforSize = 50;

void processProducer()
{
    int savePipe;
    while (value < dataAmountToProduce)
    {
        savePipe = open("pipe", O_WRONLY);
        value++;
        char str[buforSize];
        sprintf(str, "%d", value);
        printf("Producer %d produces value: %s\n", getpid(), str);
        write(savePipe, str, buforSize);
        if (value == dataAmountToProduce)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    close(savePipe);
}

void processConsumer()
{
    int readPipe;
    while (value < dataAmountToProduce)
    {
        readPipe = open("pipe", O_RDONLY);
        char buf[buforSize];
        read(readPipe, buf, buforSize);
        printf("Consumer %d consumes value: %s\n", getpid(), buf);
        value = atoi(buf);
        if (value == dataAmountToProduce)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    close(readPipe);
}

main()
{
    mkfifo("pipe", 0600);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        printf("Creating producer process %d\n", getpid());
        processProducer();
        printf("Producer process %d finished work\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        printf("Creating consumer process %d\n", getpid());
        processConsumer();
        printf("Consumer process %d finished work\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    printf("Both child processes of process %d finished work.\n", getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop to create producers, consumers

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, it is obvious, but I wish I have more detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution myself in both cases I added this block to producer method:

```
 if (value == valuesAmountToProduce)
        {
            printf("Producent process %d sent END signal\n", getpid());
            for (int i = 0; i <= amountOfConsumers; i++)
            {
                write(savePipe, "END", wielkoscBufora);
            }
```

In consumer code I'm checking if passed value is END, if yes then I'm breaking a loop:

```
if (strcmp(buf, "END") == 0)
        {
            printf("Consumer process %d recived END signal\n", getpid());
            break;
        }
```

And I solved my problem in this way, for multiple producer - single consumer we can omit consumer loop as it is in first code snippet because there will be only one consumer.